# Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work and keeps printing 0.00 km as the shortest distance?

Tags: c

This is the code I wrote. It is supposed to get the name(max 100000 characters) and the coordinates of n(max 1000) cities and calculate the euclidean distance between them. After that the program is supposed to read the starting city and the max distance to be travelled and then print the shortest path and every feasible path(a path is feasible if it's <= the max distance). When I print the dist array the values seem to be correct but the final output it totally wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int n, i, j, pos = -1, min_pos;
   char *temp = malloc(100000 * sizeof(char)), *names[1000], *start;
   float *X, *Y, max_dist, *dist[1000], min = 1000;

   if(temp == NULL)
       return 1;

   scanf("%d", &n);
   if(n < 2 || n > 1000)
      return 1;

   X = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
   Y = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
   if(X == NULL || Y == NULL)
      return 1;

  for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
  {
      scanf("%s %f %f", temp, &X[i], &Y[i]);
      names[i] = malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
      if(names[i] == NULL)
          return 1;
      strcpy(names[i], temp);
  }

  scanf("%s %f", temp, &max_dist);
  start = malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  if(start == NULL)
      return 1;
  strcpy(start, temp);
  free(temp);

  for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
      for(j = 0;j < n;j++)
      {
          dist[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
          if(dist[i] == NULL)
              return 1;
          dist[i][j] = sqrt(powf(X[j] - X[i], 2) + powf(Y[j] - Y[i], 2));
      }

  free(X);
  free(Y);

  for(i = 0;i < n && pos == -1;i++)
      if(!(strcmp(names[i], start)))
          pos = i;
  if(pos == -1)
      return 1;

  for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
      if(dist[pos][i] < min && pos != i)
      {
          min_pos = i;
          min = dist[pos][i];
      }
  printf("Shortest path is %.2f km between %s and %s\n", min, names[pos], names[min_pos]);

  for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
      if(dist[pos][i] <= max_dist && pos != i)
          printf("Feasible path of %.2f km to %s\n", dist[pos][i], names[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which of your printf statements outputs the 0.00, to which place?

Comment: Could you provide an example of input?

Comment: Hint: distance from A to A is always 0

Comment: Just an unrelated adivice: use curly parenthesis also for single instruction blocks after for/if. It will make you avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: @Kritsos Edit that into your question. Do not post that information in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were allocating memory for each `dist[i]` inside the second `for` cycle. I solved your problem by initializing `dist` as follows:

```
dist = calloc(1000, sizeof(float*));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dist[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(float));

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(dist[i] == NULL)
            return 1;
        dist[i][j] = sqrt(powf(X[j] - X[i], 2) + powf(Y[j] - Y[i], 2));
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that some instructions depended on uninitialized values. Whenever running into trouble - actually, I recommend doing this even if everything is running fine just to be sure - use `valgrind`. Compile your program with the `-ggdb3` flag and run it with valgrind. It should look something like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -o prog prog.c
valgrind ./prog
```

This will tell you about all the read/write errors, uninitialized values, memory leaks, etc. It is nice enough to even tell you exactly in which lines those things happen, so it is a great tool indeed.

On a final note, you also have some memory leaks. Here's the code you need in order to free the allocated memory:

```
free(start);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(dist[i]);
free(dist);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(names[i]);
```